# How to fit a long String into a JLabel

Tags: java, swing

as the title says: I need to fit a JLabel into a JFrame, but the text in the JLabel are too long, so I need to add some linebreaks. The text in the JLabel are obtained from an online XML file, so i cant just change the text to contain linebreaks.

This code extracts data from the XML-file

```
Element element = (Element)nodes1.item(i);
            String vær = getElementValue(element,"body");
            String v = vær.replaceAll("<.*>", "" );  
            String forecast = "Vær: " + v;
```

in this case the string I want to add some linebreaks to the string v. The String v contains the parsed data from the xml file. The String forecast is returned and set as a text to the JLabel.

Just ask if something is uncleared, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest using a `JTextArea` instead and turning wrapping on. The only way to do it in a `JLabel` is to put line breaks `<br />`, which wouldn't work (at least not easily) in your situation if you don't know the text beforehand.

`JTextArea` is much more flexible. By default it looks different, but you can fiddle around with some of the display properties to make it look like a `JLabel`.

---

A simple *modified* usage example taken from the [How to Use Text Areas](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) tutorial -

```
public class JTextAreaDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {         
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTextArea Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(
                "If there is anything the nonconformist hates worse " +
                "than a conformist, it's another nonconformist who " +
                "doesn't conform to the prevailing standard of nonconformity.", 
                6, 
                20);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 16));
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setOpaque(false);
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        panel.add(textArea);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, You may also want to make the component non-opaque (i.e. `setOpaque(false)`).

Comment: I included a simple usage example. If you feel that this is unnecessary, please let me know and I'll roll it back. :)

Comment: But how can I resize the JTextArea so it just contains certain charcaters on each line. e.g 30 Charcaters on each line before linebreak? Cus I want the JPanel to be all over the screen and not pack();

Answer (score 5):

JLabel is able to display HTML text, i.e. if you wrap your text with `<html>your text<html>` it might be able to wrap the text. That's not tested though, so YMMV.

Comment: +1, And here's a nice tutorial - [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can dynamically tell your JLabel to resize itself to fit the text.

if you are not using a LayoutManager try :

```
        jLabel.setText ("A somewaht long message I would not want to
stop");
        jLabel.setSize(jLabel.getPreferredSize());
```

If you are using a Layout Manager this snippet should work:

```
        jLabel.setText ("A somewaht long message I would not want to
stop");
        jLabel.validate();
```